# Unable to write file using xul

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

Trying to write a file inside windows temp directory using XUL code:

```
function writeFile_launch_application(utility_name,utility_path)
{
var data ='tasklist  /nh /fi "imagename eq '+utility_name+'" | find /i "'+utility_name+'">nul && (echo alerady running) || ("'+utility_path+'")';
//alert(data);
var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
       getService(Ci.nsIProperties).
       get("TmpD", Ci.nsIFile);
        file.append("launch_application.bat");
        file.createUnique(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666);

        // Then, we need an output stream to our output file.
        var ostream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].
                      createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
        ostream.init(file, -1, -1, 0);

        // Finally, we need an input stream to take data from.
        const TEST_DATA = data;
        let istream = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].
                      createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
        istream.setData(TEST_DATA, TEST_DATA.length);

        NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(aResult) {
          if (!Components.isSuccessCode(aResult)) {
            // an error occurred!
          }
        })
}
```

But getting error:

```
Timestamp: 11/29/2012 11:03:09 PM
Error: ReferenceError: Cc is not defined
Source File: chrome://myaddon/content/overlay.js
Line: 199
```

I also tried to add below lines at the top of my code but it didn't solve above error:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Cc and Ci are aliases for Components.classes and Components.interfaces respectively.

Depending on the context they might (or might not) be already defined.

In any case

```
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cu = Components.utils;
const Cr = Components.results;
```

(you shouldn't tag your question as `firefox-addon-sdk`)

Answer (score 0):

When I'm developing my addon, I always try to replace `Components.utils`, `Components.intefaces` with `Cu` and `Ci`. To do that, first line in my file is:

```
const { Cc, Ci, Cu } = require('chrome');
```

`Cc` is `Component.classes`. Than you can use now

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
```

Comment: Now its saying "require is not defined"

Comment: Are you using Addon Builder? I've had a lot of problem using it and now I develop with `cfx`. Try to close/refresh browser and clean its cache.

Comment: Try to use Addon Builder or other tool. I don't know, how exactly it works, but this can help you i.e. include needed libraries. You can make you addon private, so nobody can see it.

Comment: Did it help you? Post comment, because I wonder what is the solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20400/discussion-between-tomasz-dz-and-user1862780)